# External Server can't register non-ascii characters to MYSQL database.

Tags: mysql, non-ascii-characters

I am 100% able to register non-ASCII characters into my database using INTERNAL server (LOCALHOST) (with remote access to the database) but I'm not able to INSERT on my database or even to read non-ASCII characters from the database when I use the EXTERNAL SERVER.

Is there any solution to that?

Resume: Everythings works fine on localhost, but external server can't read or write non-ASCII characters on MYSQL database.

Aditional information:

- When external server inserts a string with non-ASCII characters, it changes the string. Example: "pão integral (S)" is modified to "pÃ£o integral (S)".
- If the string is registered as "pÃ£o integral (S)" (for example) on the database, then the external server can read just fine, and it reads as "pão integral (S)". However, I don't want my database to have strings like "pÃ£o integral (S)" registered.

Comment: An encoding can be set per connection. If you connect using JDBC you can use an URL like jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but my problem is not the localhost. My problem is the external host. What I want is to my external host work as well as localhost.

Comment: The URL is only an example. Localhost simply has to be replaced for a remote connection.